# Doctrine2 how to see a generated createQuery SQL Text (symfony2)

Tags: doctrine-orm

I would like to get the 'real' SQL Query doctrine is passing to the SQL Server:

```
<?php
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

$myQuery = $em->createQuery('SELECT v FROM ....... v');
echo $myQuery->???????

?>
```

What I must to write instead of ???????? characters ?

I have tried with getSQLQuery() and with getSQL() but no luck for now.

Thanks..

Answer (score 8):

You were almost there, it's **getSql**, not **getSQL**:

```
$myQuery->getSql()
```

Comment: Functions are case-insensitive in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
$myQuery->getResult();
```

Comment: Perhaps you are right.  I don't know and I cannot test it because I have switched to Symfony and I don't know how I can delete a question neither.

Answer (score 0):

See if it helps

```
$myQuery->getDql();
```